# module 'Lowesthighest' has no attribute 'l' while it has a attribute defined as l

Tags: python

I am making a simple number guesser game and for some reason i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Number Guesser\Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    Guess.guesser()
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Number Guesser\Guess.py", line 5, in guesser
    numguess = int(input("Guess a number between" + Lowesthighest.l + "and" + Lowesthighest.h))
AttributeError: module 'Lowesthighest' has no attribute 'l'
```

Here i will put all of my code (i have it in diffrent files):

Guess.py

```
import Lowesthighest


def guesser():
    numguess = int(input("Guess a number between" + Lowesthighest.l + "and" + Lowesthighest.h))

    if numguess > Lowesthighest.h:
        print('Your guess, ' + '"{}"'.format(numguess) + "is more than " + Lowesthighest.h)
    elif numguess < Lowesthighest.l:
        print('Your guess, ' + '"{}"'.format(numguess) + "is less than " + Lowesthighest.l)   
    else: 
        print("Congratulations, Your guess, " + '"{}"'.format(numguess) + "was correct!")
```

Lowesthighest.py

```
def lh():
    l = int(input("Lowest Number: "))
    h = int(input("Highest Number: "))
```

Main.py

```
import Guess

Guess.guesser()
```

I think it is due to the reason l and h are inside a function and i try to call it only through the file, might be wrong but i don't know.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `l` and `h` are *local variables* inside a function.  Even if you actually called the function, the variables would not be accessible ANYWHERE outside of the function.

Comment: @jasonharper should i call them as global?

Comment: Making them global doesn't help unless you also call the function.

Comment: You forgot to call that `lh` function

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables outside the function, and call them globally inside the function.

```
l, h = None, None
def lh():
    global l, h
    l = int(input("Lowest Number: "))
    h = int(input("Highest Number: "))
```

Keep in mind that this would only work if you called the function before calling the variables. Otherwise, it will return an error because they would be None

Comment: None means like nothing in the python index?

Comment: If you're referring to the value returned by `lh`, then yes, because it hasn't returned anything, it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

- make the variables `l` and `h` global.
- call the function

```py
global l
global h
def lh():
    l = int(input("Lowest Number: "))
    h = int(input("Highest Number: "))
lh()
```

**or** simply write this in your file, its much more easier:

```py
l = int(input("Lowest Number: "))
h = int(input("Highest Number: "))
```

Comment: The error is still there i tried the answer above and it worked but i got another error due to the None i think

Comment: Could you write the error here?. I think you need also to call that function

Comment: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: i wrote it, i hope you can help me

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it works :)

Comment: @ItsMeData you must call the function, otherwise the value of the variable will remain None and will not change